# Should I use the singular or plural?

Tags: singular-subject-and-verb

> I got awards for best actor, best director, and best animator.

Is the plural “awards” the correct word to use or should I use the singular “I got AN award for best actor, best director, and best animator”?

Comment: To me, "an award" suggests that there was a single award for being the best actor/director/amimator.

Comment: If he holds three trophies in his hands at the end of the day, use plural. If he holds only one, then singular.

Comment: The distributive singular (your second version) is probably grammatical, but, as your first variant partially disambiguates (it forces a 'more than 1 award' interpretation) it is better. But if we're embracing the Gricean maxim of manner (which includes 'avoid ambiguity') we should use 'I got an/the award for best actor, an/the award for best director, and an/the award for best animator.' Assuming only 3 awards in total, ie one per category, were involved.